# Why does my Android project fail to build after updating my SDK to include v20 and the latest build tools?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After upgrading my build tools to the latest versions (SDK Tools v23, Platform Tools v20, and Android Studio v0.8.1) I got the following error building my project:

> uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version L declared in
>   library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1

This didn't make any sense to me since my project explicitly defines the support version to be 19.1.0 everywhere it is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized that a library I was including was actually requesting an unbounded version of the support library which resulted in the L preview version being included.

To fix this, I added the following:

```
compile ('name_of_library:0.9.9') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-v4'
}
```

Provided you include a version of the support library greater than or equal to the minimum version used by that library, everything should work fine.

To help identify the offending library, type the following:

```
./gradlew :your_project_name:dependencies
```

You'll get a handy spew output showing the dependencies of your project and what versions they all get mapped to.

Comment: where exactly in the build.gradle do you add it?

Comment: Because after I added it I got a build script error :(

Comment: When you id the library that is at fault, replace the instance where you put the dependency (ie: the compile line) with the one above. Essentially you are just adding the { exclude ... } stuff to your existing dependency declaration.